# condional rendering with a redirect

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, visualforce

Here is the set up. I have a standard page layout with custom buttons.

When the user clicks a button, i want to check a value in the extension class. If the value is null or 0- i want a pages message to appear, otherwise i want to redirect them to another **VF** page.

the way that i'm **attempting** to do this is put a VF section on the page layout, and have it conditionally rendered using an action:support method, but I can't get it to work..

HALP!

Comment: Any chance you can post some of your code? Also, make sure you have your "rerender" attributes set correctly - you generally want to rerender some sort of wrapper around your VF section.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to add a VF page to the layout.
Try to use the Salesforce AJAX Toolkit for your custom button:

1) First create a WebService to calculate your value:

```java
global with sharing class yourController{
    WebService static Integer calculateValue(Integer i) { 
        Integer result = i + 5;
        return result; 
    }
}
```

2) Then create a custom button for your object:
 Display Type -
*Detail Page Button*
 Behavior - *Execute JavaScript*
 Content Source - *onClick JavaScript*

3) Then add this code to the button:

```js
// Loading the ajax toolkit data
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/20.0/connection.js")}
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/10.0/apex.js")}

// Making a call to the webservice method
var value = sforce.apex.execute("yourController","calculateValue", {i:5});

// If the value is 0 or blank            
if(value == 0 || value == ''){
    // Pop up a message
    alert('Your message text here');
else{
    // Otherwise redirecting user to another page
    window.location = "/apex/YourCustomPage";
}
```

4) Now save your button and do not forget to add it to the layout page :)

Answer (score 0):

If the method called from the button returns a `PageReference`, you can create a `PageReference` object and use the `.setRedirect( True)` method to do a redirect.  You're probably returning `Null` right now, which indicates "no action".

You can set the target of the redirect when you create the `PageReference`, or use the `new ApexPages.StandardController()` method to select one of the controllers for a given object type, or just `Page.vfPageName` to reference another Visualforce page.

When your method returns that `PageReference`, the browser will redirect to the new URL.